# Formula not evolving when inserting column

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a basic Excel file like this :

[image]

The columns from M to P are completed automatically with another sheets in the same workbook by looking the reference in column E.

But I want to add a new column before E by using the openpyxl lib in python, I tryed the following code:

```
wb = load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
sheet.insert_cols(5)
wb.save(file_path)
```

It insert a new column perfectly, but the problem is the formula in my cell from M to P are not evolving, they keep the old reference from my column E, so after inserting my column the new reference would be F and not E like the following example.

[image]

Someone know how to solve that ? Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: From the documentation: **Openpyxl does not manage dependencies, such as formulae, tables, charts, etc., when rows or columns are inserted or deleted.**

Comment: Oh I don't know that, there is a way to do it in other way ? or another lib ?

Comment: @TheeAntoine win32com or xlwings might do what you want